# Can I use token-pasting and/or stringizing for #includes?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, stringification

Let's say I've got a few files, that are all similarly named: `Foo1Bar.h`, `Foo2Bar.h`, `Foo3Bar.h`, etc etc. Now, I want to auto-include those in some `main.c` in a "plug-in" style, that is, I don't want to have to remember to `#include` each one. Is it possible to do this with token-pasting? So far, I've got:

```
// this is the only line I want to have to change if I add Foo4Bar.h
#define FOR_EACH_FOOBAR(T) T(1)T(2)T(3)
//... somewhere else in my code
#define RUN_SOME_FUNC(T) Foo##T##Bar().run();
```

And the above works fine (assuming of course all my `Foo*Bar.h` files have classes `Foo*Bar` with a public `run()` method. (In case it isn't clear, my example here is C++, but I don't think the question itself, with `#include`, is C++ specific).

What I'm having trouble teasing out is if I can do this with my `#include` statements as well. Instead of

```
#include <Foo1Bar.h>
#include <Foo2Bar.h>
#include <Foo3Bar.h>
#include <Foo4Bar.h>
```

it would be nicer (to me) to alter things like:

```
FOR_EACH_FOOBAR(T) T(1)T(2)T(3)T(4)
FOR_EACH_FOOBAR(INCLUDE)
```

I tried:

```
#define INCLUDE(T) #include <Foo##T##Bar.h>
```

but get the error: `'#' is not followed by a macro parameter`, because it's trying to stringize the beginning portion. Any convolution or gyration I've tried has resulted in the same (or similar) error, and I can't figure out how to either escape the `#include` or whatever to get this to work.

Is it possible, and if so, how? If not, is there a precise reason why not?

Comment: I know that point, I've been there, too. That's when one wishes to have Lisp-like macros :) I guess instead of trying to do this "in" your source files add a step to your build process to produce a `AllFooBars.h` header with all those includes.

Comment: @DanielJour oh good point, I wasn't thinking about anything outside the source files, but that sounds reasonable. Thanks for the thought - regardless of whether or not it is possible to do in C, the build is probably the way to go.

Comment: The bottom line is: you are not allowed to use preprocessor macro expansion to generate preprocessor directives. So, you are not allowed to generate `#include` directives. With `#include`, it is OK to specify the file name through a macro, but that's about all you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you want because the `#` commands are processed by the preprocessor and it doesn't look too see if another `#` command results from the expansion but there is some functionality for "generating" `#include` lines, they just come after the `#include` text itself...

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Computed-Includes.html

Search here for "#include anything else": https://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/gnu-info/cpp_1.html

Comment: One notable asterisk is that Microsoft has an extension to allow `#pragma` to be issued as the result of a macro expansion, but that has little to do with the OP.

Comment: The part: "it doesn't look to see if another `#` command results from the expansion" is the answer I was looking (though not hoping) for - that explains WHY there isn't any possible way for me to get the `#define FOR_EACH...` to ever work for `#include`s (which is fine, at least now I know).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use:

```
#define INCLUDE(T) #include Foo##T##Bar.h
```

since the `#` is used as an operator to stringify the argument.

```
#define STR(x) #x

char const* s = STR(THIS);
```

is the same as using:

```
char const* s = "THIS";
```

Given that,

```
#define INCLUDE(T) #include Foo##T##Bar.h
```

suffers from the problem that `include` is not one of the parameters of the macro. Hence, use of `#include` is not legal.

**Update**

I don't think standard C preprocessor functionality can be used to accomplish what you wish to accomplish. Personally, I would rather see

```
#include <Foo1Bar.h>
#include <Foo2Bar.h>
#include <Foo3Bar.h>
#include <Foo4Bar.h>
```

in my file than

```
FOR_EACH_FOOBAR(T) T(1)T(2)T(3)T(4)
FOR_EACH_FOOBAR(INCLUDE)
```

Comment: Right, I was aware of that based on the error I received when trying to compile. My question is: is there any way around that? I'm not very familiar/comfortable with token-pasting and stringizing so I'm wondering if there's just a more clever work-around I need.

Comment: @dwanderson, can you add to your post a few lines showing how you wish to use this macro and how it will make your life simpler when you add Foo4Bar.h?

Comment: I agree with regard to the indicated example.  On the other hand, I'd much rather see something like `#include QLIB_HEADERS("qlib.h")` than `#include "../../qlib/headers/qlib.h"` or `#include "qlib.h" // Hope an include path manages to find the right thing`.